# QGIS - RGB multiband to HSB(HSV?) multiband

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, rgb

I need to calculate the following index on parts of a drone image (RGB multiband)

**DGCI = [(Hue - 60)/60 + (1 - Saturation) + (1 - Brightness)]/3**

Is HSB the same as HSV?

How do I convert my entire .tif RGB to a HSB(HSV?). I found a way to convert values individually using `colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r,g,b)`.

How can I apply that and have a multiband HSB(HSV?) file output?

I've tried to use the raster calculator using https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556341/rgb-to-hsv-color-conversion-algorithm.

Comment: Please edit your post to include a single, focused question.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the 2nd part of your question (the conversion): unfortunately, while QGIS has functions that manipulate colours in expressions (see https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#color-functions), those expressions work on vector layers and not in the raster calculator, which is implemented differently.

When I've needed to transform and extract raster color information, I've used the `raster` package in R instead. In particular, if you load an RGB raster as a brick, then `hsvbrick <- overlay(brick,fun=rgb2hsv)` will get you a brick where it is transformed into hsv space. You could then save `hsvbrick[[3]]` to get the just the V part, for instance, changing as you see fit for your calculation, and for displaying in QGIS. Or you could save the whole hsvbrick and then use it with @1, @2, @3 in the QGIS raster calculator.

I'm sure you could develop a python/PyQGIS solution that would use `gdal`, `numpy` and `colorsys` instead of R and operate from within the QGIS platform, if needed.

Adding: Some types of raster color transformations can be achieved by loading the RGB raster, then fiddling with the `Symbology / Color rendering` settings, and then `Export / Save as` with Output mode = Rendered Image rather than Raw Data. But this won't be enough when you actually need all 3 components; esp hue.